# Copy from two cells text to clipboard with vba

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I wish to create a VBA code so I can put a shortcut to copy from two different cells into the clipboard so I can save a file with the exact name.

[image: final text like this]

Whenever I use the shortcut, from the active line, the code should copy from the line in column G and then put a space and a hyphen and another space and copy the line from column E and throw at the clipboard so I can rename a respective file to this very line.

---

@edit¹
The code the guy gave me worked but it can't keep the leading zeros.
The cell format is `.NumberFormat = #000000000`, and the code only gets the value of the cell.
Using the example, the code copy's like `TRANSPORTE GARCIA - 32021`.
Any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy String to Clipboard (DAO)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyName()
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Dim cString As String
        With Selection.Rows(1).EntireRow
            cString = .Range("G1").Value & " - " & .Range("E1").Value
        End With
        With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
            .SetText cString
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: friend, I got a problem with the code. the zeros before the number are not being copied.

Comment: Try `cString = .Range("G1").Value & " - " & Format(.Range("E1").value, "#000000000")`.